# Show that $g(x)=x\ln{x}$ and $g(x)=e^x$ are bounded below.

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-function

Show that $g(x)$ is bounded below, for $0\leq x$:

a) 
$g(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  0  & \mbox{if } x=0 \\
  x\ln{x} & \mbox{if } x>0
 \end{array}
\right.$

b) $g(x)=e^x$

For (a), $g(x)\geq0$ for $x\geq0$.

For (b), $g(x)\geq1$ for $x\geq0$.

Is that all I have to say? Or is there a more technical definition/proof?

Comment: In (a), what is $g\left(e^{-1}\right)$?

Comment: @GitGud Oh I must be tired! For (a), $g(x)\geq -e^{-1}$. Anyway, is that all I have to say?

Comment: Those assertions indeed imply that $g$ is bounded below, however I really can't tell what is expected from you. For (a) I would assume you'd have to find $\lim \limits _0 \,g$ and prove that $g$ is increasing.

Comment: @sammydean can you *show* that $g(x) \geq -e^{-1}$?

Comment: @GitGud I can't tell what is expected from me either, but thanks for your input. And $lim_{x\to 0} g(x)=0$ but $g$ is not increasing for $0\leq x \leq e^{-1}$?

Comment: @sammydean You're right, it's not. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

For a) you can show that $g(x)$ attains a minimum on $(0, \infty)$ by setting $g'(x) = 0$ and verifying that its critical point is a local minimum.

For b) you can note that $g(0) = 1$ and that $g(x)$ is increasing.